# AngularFire how to get $firebaseArray.$watch to include old value and new value in the change event?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to watch for specific changes to some data, and it doesn't like like I can do so with the AngularFire $watch function. It only returns the key and the event type, but not the old and new values.

[Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-watchcallback-context)

How can I get the old and new values whenever an array element is changed?

Comment: I'm a little but unsure of what you're asking here, surely you can use child_added and child_removed watchers to handle each of those instances with their contents? Could you give me a bit more information on what you're trying to accomplish with the watcher? So that I can make sure I give you the best answer for your problem

Comment: @Grant I'm using the AngularFire $watch to watch for updates. Changing a value of an entry triggers the AngularFire $watch event, which provides the key and the event type. No other information such as old and new value. I want to know what the old value was before the change was made, in the same manner the vanilla $watch works.

Comment: You cannot return the values into `$watch` however you can receive the key and the `prevChild` which will contain the key or null depending on the event -- I tend to find AngularFire is not a complete solution for the things I am trying to accomplish and I generally need to set up `child_added` and `child_removed` watchers which will then store the values somewhere for me to use -- See if this helps: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html